# An iterative rather than recursive algorithm to find all ways to split n into m pieces

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I need a function that takes two integers, let's say n and m, where n >= 0 and m >= 1, which returns a list of lists, containing every possible way to split n up into the m positive integer pieces (Order matters, [4, 7, 2] is distinct from [7, 4, 2].)
Now, I was able to come up with a quick little recursive function that does the job, shown below:

```
def split(number, elements):
    if elements == 1:
        return [[number]]
    ways = []
    for i in range(0, number + 1):
        for j in split_number(number - i, elements - 1):
            values.append([i] + j)
    return values
```

However, I might be using it with large numbers and therefore need to convert it to an iterative method. I haven't been sure how to do this because it calls itself multiple times per 'supercall', making it difficult to even convert to tail calls and accumulators, much less use them to convert to an iterative form.

Sample outputs:

```
split(7, 2) -> [[0, 7], [1, 6], [2, 5], [3, 4], [4, 3], [5, 2], [6, 1], [7, 0]]
split(4, 3) -> [[0, 0, 4], [0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 2], [0, 3, 1], [0, 4, 0], [1, 0, 3], 
[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 0], [2, 0, 2], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 0], [3, 0, 1], [3, 1, 0],
[4, 0, 0]]
```

etc.

Comment: If it's an exercise, then try to implement it. Otherwise, [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) may be what you want.

Comment: @zyxue It's not an excersize, I just need the code. I don't see how `permutations` helps me, though. I can't think of a set where all permutations of it add to some number.

Comment: Permutations can be used to generate elements missing from combinations_with_replacement from those produced by it and which sum to number. For example combinations_with_replacement(range(5),3) generates (0, 0, 4) but not (4, 0, 0) or (0, 4, 0) which are permutations of it.

Comment: Right, use `combinations_with_replacement` makes more sense, please see my answer. It's a bit tricky to get it all right.

Comment: Your title and question do not match - is it n into m or m into n?

Comment: Oh whoops. Will fix the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way using itertools:

```
def chainsplit(n,p):
    return sorted(list(set(chain.from_iterable([list(permutations(i,len(i))) 
        for i in list(combinations_with_replacement(range(n+1),p)) if sum(i) == n]))))
```

Here are several timeit benchmarks showing the overhead for list conversion, sorting and function invocation:

```
%timeit set(chain.from_iterable([list(permutations(i,len(i))) for i in list(combinations_with_replacement(range(5),3)) if sum(i) == 4]))
10000 loops, best of 3: 20 µs per loop

%timeit list(set(chain.from_iterable([list(permutations(i,len(i))) for i in list(combinations_with_replacement(range(5),3)) if sum(i) == 4])))
10000 loops, best of 3: 20.4 µs per loop

%timeit sorted(list(set(chain.from_iterable([list(permutations(i,len(i))) for i in list(combinations_with_replacement(range(5),3)) if sum(i) == 4]))))
10000 loops, best of 3: 25 µs per loop

%timeit chainsplit(4,3)
10000 loops, best of 3: 26.4 µs per loop
```

Here is a benchmark for @zyxue's numpy-based function f() for comparison:

```
timeit f(4,3)
10000 loops, best of 3: 133 µs per loop
```

Running your split() function froze my kernel so I was unable to timeit.  Note that in it split_function should be changed to split or change the function name to split_function for it to work. split_function may be the better choice to avoid confusion with other functions named split.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

def f(n, m):
    r = combinations_with_replacement(xrange(n + 1), m - 1)
    return [np.diff([0] + list(x) + [n]).tolist() for x in r]


assert f(7, 2) == [[0, 7], [1, 6], [2, 5], [3, 4], [4, 3], [5, 2], [6, 1], [7, 0]]
assert f(4, 3) == [[0, 0, 4], [0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 2], [0, 3, 1], [0, 4, 0], [1, 0, 3],
                   [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 0], [2, 0, 2], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 0],
                   [3, 0, 1], [3, 1, 0], [4, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a queue of unfinished jobs.

An unfinished job is a list of numbers, where the first element can be potentially split further.   Pull a job from the queue, split the first element in every possible way, and add the resulting jobs back to the queue.

The algorithm is as follows (eclectic pseudocode)

```
Q = new Queue
Q.enqueue ([n])
While not Q.empty:
   l = Q.dequeue()
   Output.append(l)
   h = l.head
   t = l.tail
   If h != 1:
     For each i in 1 .. h-1:
       Q.enqueue ([i,h-i]++t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive-turned-iterative approach in Python:

```
def f(n,m):
  stack = [([n] + (m - 1)*[0],0)]
  result = []
  while len(stack) > 0:
    (p,i) = stack.pop()
    if i == m - 1:
      result.append(p)
    else:
      for k in xrange(0,p[i] + 1):
        _p = p[:]
        _p[i] = _p[i] - k
        _p[i + 1] = p[i + 1] + k
        stack.append((_p,i + 1))
  return result

print(f(4,3))
print(f(7,2))
```